# Spell Checking Repeated Letters

Tags: algorithm, spell-checking, trie

I am writing a spell checker. I know all about Levenshtein distance, tries etc...

My issue however is, to correct a word with repeated letters such as: haaaaapppppyyy to happy. What would be the best way to tackle this?

So far I am thinking of using a modified trie whereby when I reach "a" and see there isn't another following "a" in the trie, I skip all a's in the string until I get to p and proceed from there.

I'm not entirely sure this is the best way to implement it though or if it will work on all strings.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It definitely won't work on all strings, but I'm guessing it will work for about 99.99% of them :p

Comment: What is the purpose of the spell checking? Is it for humans or as a feed to a machine? (If the later, using stemming can resolve the issue, since stemmers will remove most of duplicate letters anyway, and cannonize all words into their stemmed form)

Comment: Humans. So you may type: hhhhaaaappppyyy and it should suggest 'happy' as a replacement.

Comment: Have you looked into Hidden Markov models?

Comment: What is your data? Can you afford going on-line? Do you have some corpus? Or just a dictionary?

Comment: Just a dictionary. I am trying to implement an algorithm in less than O(n), so I may only scan it once (and populate the trie at scan-time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new trie with all repeated letters removed (e.g. happy -> hapy). When checking for a word, do the same thing (haaaaapppppyyy -> hapy) and search it in the trie.

Comment: Note it will have no way to difference between "bleed" and "bled" (which might be a good or bad thing, depending on the application)